# How to put multiple Katakana or Latin letters in a single CJK block?

Tags: fonts, japanese

In [the Unicode Standard document, v. 13](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/UnicodeStandard-13.0.pdf), it says on p. 877 (bold-facing mine):

> Squared Katakana words are Katakana-spelled words that fill a single display cell (em-square) when intermixed with CJK ideographs. Likewise, the square Latin abbreviation symbols are designed to fill a single character position when mixed with CJK ideographs. **Note that modern software for the East Asian market can often support the comparable functionality via styles that allow typesetting of arbitrary Katakana words or Latin abbreviations in an em-square.** Such solutions are preferred when available, as they are not limited to specific lists of encoded symbols such as those in this block.

This sounds quite remarkable to me. Where or with what fonts and software can I try that out? (I’m completely new to this. Also, I don’t know if this is the right StackExchange forum to ask, but there is no typography related one and the others didn’t fit at all.)

Comment: If you ever find the typography exchange, please let us know here. You can edit your own question later.

Comment: There IS an exchange for software recommendations here:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but people in graphicdesign might know more about typography.

Comment: At least I’m not the only one on the web who thinks that a typography StackExchange should exist.

Comment: Perhaps something you could ask about on the Japanese Stack Exchange site. Maybe try their chat rooms and speak to some users first before posting. I don't know if this would be on topic there. I suppose you could reword the question and not concentrate on the software aspect of this question. I think for graphic design this might be a bit too niche TBH, and also software recommendations are generally off-topic here anyway.

Comment: @Bolpat You know how it is, we would be welcome to set it up ourselves. Not-sadly I am overworked at my main job; I like my job. If you got capacity, read up on Stackexchange and you will find instructions on how to set up a new exchange. If you make a first move, I am confident that others will join you. I would certainly sign up as a user, but cannot be on staff, sorry.